# Guardar informacion en un archivo de texto y como pedirla(c++)

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema para guardar informacion en un archivo .txt
Queria saber que tipo de codigo podria utilizar.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <string>
```

Son las librerias que estoy utilizando

Comment: Por favor, muestra el código erróneo que tienes y describe el error (comportamiento esperado/obtenido). Así como está, la pregunta da a entender que buscas un ejemplo. Y de esos hay **miles** en Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guardar información en un archivo de texto utilizando la clase [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) y sus métodos `open` y `close` para gestionar el archivo y el operador `<<` para escribir en él.

Un ejemplo sencillo, sería:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream miarchivo;
  miarchivo.open ("ejemplo.txt");
  miarchivo << "Hola mundo en un archivo de texto.\n";
  miarchivo.close();
  return 0;
}
```